# Problem with table in SAPGUI (LoadRunner)

Tags: csv, loadrunner

Please tell me how I can pull out the entire table of transaction SM37 in SAP and write it to a file CSV in the format:

NameJOB1, Number 1, Number 2, Number 3.

NameJOB2, Number 1, Number 2, Number 3.

I don't know the language well "С" need help on question.

Answer (score 0):

So, how will you manage lock with tens or hundreds of users writing to a file?   You need to send this to a service.  May I suggest the Virtual Table Server (ships with LoadRunner) or one of the queue services with Amazon, Azure, Google or IBM clouds